# How to find probability for $B$ to win the game?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $A$ and $B$ toss a coin alternative till one of them gets a head and win the game, if $A$ starts first, what is probability for $B$ to win the game?

Comment: How far have you gotten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is basically asking for the probability of one of the following strings: 
$$
TH, TTTH, TTTTTH, TTTTTTTH, \dots
$$
The probability of each $n^{th}$ string happening in any given $2n$ flips  is $1/4^n$. Therefore
$$
P(\text{B wins})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{4^n}=\frac{1}{3}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Call that probability $p$. If Alice's first toss is heads *(assuming a fair coin all throughout, that has probability $1/2$)*, she wins. Otherwise, it's exactly the same game, but now Bob starts (so in this analogous game where *he* starts, roles are swapped: $p$ is Alice's probability of winning, and Bob's is $1-p$). This gives:
$$
 p = \frac{1}{2}(1-p)
$$
*(Can you see why?)* and therefore $\boxed{p = 1/3}$.